# organize nodes in a list of data with tree structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, tree

I'm using typescript (for an angular project) and I have a class like this:

```
class Encyc {
  constructor(id: number, parentId: number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.parentId = parentId;
  }

  // these fields come from server side
  private _id: number;
  private _parentId: number;

  // extra variable
  private _hasChildren: boolean;
  private _children: Encyc[];

  // getters and setters
}
```

imagine that I fetch a list like this from server:

```
[
  Encyc(1, null),
  Encyc(2, null),
  Encyc(3, 1),
  Encyc(4, 1),
  Encyc(5, 3),
  Encyc(6, 2),
  Encyc(7, 4),
  Encyc(8, null),
  Encyc(9, 2),
  Encyc(10, 5)
]
```

now I need a method to get this data, set children of each parent and return a list like this:

```
[
  Encyc(1, null, true, [
    Encyc(3, 1, true, [
      Encyc(5, 3, true, [
        Encyc(10, 5, false, [])
      ])
    ]),

    Encyc(4, 1, true, children[
      Encyc(7, 4, false, [])
    ])
  ]),

  Encyc(2, null, true, [
    Encyc(6, 2, false, []),
    Encyc(9, 2, false, [])
  ]),

  Encyc(8, null, false, [])
]
```

at the first, I got a list of 10 items in it, then (after the function that I need) the list will contain just 3 items. the first one has 2 direct children and all of its children counts is 5

so is there any library or algorithms for something like this?